# Tensorflow estimator input function: defining each feature or not?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

With `x` is a 120 x 4 feature matrix of Iris data (4 features) and `y` is a label, I can make an input function for `tf.estimator` like below

```
def input_function(x, y):
    dict_x = {
        "sepal_length" : x[:,0],
        "sepal_width" :  x[:,1],
        "petal_length" : x[:,2],
        "petal_width" :  x[:,3]
    }

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
        dict_x, y
    ))

    return dataset
```

then define the feature column like below:

```
feature_columns = [
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="sepal_length"),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="sepal_width"),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="petal_length"),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="petal_width")
]
```

But, I found in the internet (I forget the source, still searching) that I also can define the input function like below. The difference with previous method is all four features now defined with only one key, `"x"`.

```
def input_function(x, y):
    dict_x = {
        "x" : x,
    }

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
        dict_x, y
    ))

    return dataset
```

then define the feature column like below:

```
feature_columns = [
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="x",shape=4),
]
```

I've run both method and both give almost same result. **My question**: I can't find any documentation that explain the difference between both method, because at a glance `dict_x` have different shape. Are they still treated equally at input layer on neural networks?

I'm new using `tf.estimator`, Thank You

My estimator code if needed:

```
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    hidden_units=[10],
    n_classes=3,
    optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001),
    activation_fn=tf.nn.relu
)

# Train the model
classifier.train(
    input_fn=lambda:input_function(xtrain, ytrain, True)
)
```

Comment: you might have seen the approach of using a dict with "x" and the whole feature set mapped to this only key in the image recognition tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn. Specifically for images, where the individual pixels may not have any meaning, as opposed to the whole image, it can be practical to use a multi-dimensional feature (in the case of images, a tensor with all the pixels). Then some specific layer objects which work with images (for example tf.layers.conv2d) will perfectly understand this multi-dimensional feature as the whole image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of `numeric_column` with same `dtype`'s the only difference is shape of the resultant input:

Option 1 creates input of shape: `[120,4,1]`: 120 samples, each represented by 4 vectors of 1 number.

Whereas option 2 creates input of shape: `[120,1,4]`: 120 samples, each represented by a single vector consisting of 4 numbers.

In the end, it does not really matter because both get flattened to `[120,4]` before being fed to the network.

---

First I created the features.

```
features1 = {
    'sepal_length' : np.random.rand(120),
    'sepal_width': np.random.rand(120),
    'petal_length': np.random.rand(120),
    'petal_width': np.random.rand(120)
}

features2 = {
    'everything' : np.random.rand(120, 4)
}
```

Then I prepared the feature columns -- same as you did.

```
feature_columns1 = [
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="sepal_length"),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="sepal_width"),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="petal_length"),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="petal_width")
]

feature_columns2 = [
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="everything", shape=4),
]
```

Now, to see what exactly is done with them when they're fed to the network we can use the `feature_column.input_layer()`.

```
inputs1 = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features1, feature_columns1)
inputs2 = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features2, feature_columns2)
```

And as we can see, both ways produced the same shape.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    res1 = sess.run(inputs1)
    res2 = sess.run(inputs2)
```

```
print(res1.shape)
print(res2.shape)
(120, 4)
(120, 4)
```

Comment: is there a complete documentation I can read? I mean, in which part?

Comment: You can read about it **mostly** more [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/programmers_guide/low_level_intro#feature_columns), [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/feature_columns) and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/numeric_column). Easiest way is to experiment -- check my updated answer.